# div relative to top moves up when you resize the window?

Tags: html, css

Ok I have a div here bandG:

```css
#outercontainer {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  border: solid 1pt lightgray;
  padding: 5%;
}

#bandR {
  width: 90%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: darkred;
  opacity: .1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: -5;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

#bandG {
  width: 95%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 190%;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<div id="outercontainer">

  <div id="bandR">
  </div>
  <div id="bandG">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <strong>Foraging</strong>
```

The issue occurs when I resize the page, the bandG moves relative to the top and doesn't keep a static distance from the bottom. I've tried setting it relative to the bottom with a percent, but it then ends up at the top of the page.

As is I go from:

[image]

to

[image]

when resizing. How can I keep static distance from bottom?

Comment: Please tell me what exactly you what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get your question right, if I understand it correctly, you want both boxes fixed despite the resizing.

I came up with this:

```css
#outercontainer {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  border: solid 1pt lightgray;
  padding: 5%;
}

#outercontainer:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 90%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: darkred;
  opacity: .1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: -5;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

#outercontainer:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 95%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 190%;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<div id="outercontainer">

  <div id="bandR">
  </div>
  <div id="bandG">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <strong>Foraging</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using pseudo selectors will keep things in their places.